# How to get email field in tracking event jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to fire a tracking use by email so have the following code

```
$('.form').submit(function() {
var email = $('#form-field').val();

theTracking('userEmail', 'email'); 


});
```

Why email veriable not returning the email value?

Comment: What is `theTracking` here? Could you please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. if not working show me what is in your console.

```
$('.form').submit(() => {
  const email = $('#form-field').val();

  console.log('email:', email);
  console.log('form-field:', $('#form-field'));

  theTracking('userEmail', email); 
});
```